# Rename column name based on the Value

Tags: sql-server

I need to rename the column base on the value I give in it.

```
SELECT TOP 1  
  [Pratice_Id] = [OID]// id
  , [Province] = '' //province
  , [Country] = 'US'// country   
FROM [tbl_Office]
```

if the country equals to US  I want to change columnName [Province] to State

Comment: Can you explain why you care what the column name is? Surely your client app can adjust the label to suit?

Comment: You can't change the column name, but you could add a column with a case expression to return a label.

Comment: Or you can add 2 columns, 1 Province, 1 State and your client app selects the correct one.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest a column `STATE_PROVINCE`, however, if you **MUST** and you are not opposed to a temp table, perhaps something like this

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 *
 Into  #Temp
 From  YourTable
 Where ...
 Order By ...

If ( Select Top 1 Country From #Temp  ) = 'US'
    Select [Pratice_Id]
          ,[State]  = [Province]
          ,[Country]
     From  #Temp
Else
    Select * from #Temp
```

**Returns**

```
Pratice_Id  State   Country
1           RI       US
```

**Personally, I would provide both**

```
Declare @YourTable table ([Pratice_Id] int,[Province] varchar(50),[Country] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'RI','US')
,(2,'Alberta','Canada')

Select [Pratice_Id]
      ,[State]      = case when [Country]='US' then Province else '' end
      ,[Province]   = case when [Country]<>'US' then Province else '' end
      ,[Country]
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
Pratice_Id  State   Province    Country
1            RI                 US
2                   Alberta     Canada
```